# Crossfilter can't filter one dimension by another

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, crossfilter

[jsFiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/eWr8Z/4/)

I'm trying to filter over two dimensions in Crossfilter.  I have an array of data that repeats a given object:

```
{
    "bioguide_id" : "O000167",
    "first_name" : "Barack",
    "last_name" : "Obama",
    "party" : "Democrat",
    "religion" : "United Church of Christ",
    "pac_id" : "C00404145",
    "pac_name" : "Mendocino County Democratic Central Committee",
    "contribution_count" : 4,
    "contribution_sum" : 1264,
    "congress" : 110
}
```

I have the following query to crossfilter working perfectly:

```
var contributions = data.dimension(function(c) { return c.contribution_sum; });

contributions.top(3).forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log(p.pac_name + " (" + p.congress + ")" + ": $" + p.contribution_sum);
});
```

**However, how can I get the top X `contribution_sum`'s from Y `congress`?**  I've attempted the following to no avail:

```
var congress = data.dimension(function(c) { return c.congress; });

congress.filter(111).group().order(function(c) { return c.contribution_sum; }).top(3).forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log(p.pac_name + " (" + p.congress + ")" + ": $" + p.contribution_sum);
});
```

Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will want to filter on your 'congress' dimension and then ask for the top members of your 'contribution_sum' dimension like:

```
var congress = data.dimension(function(c) { return +c.congress; });
var contributions = data.dimension(function(c) { return +c.contribution_sum; });

congress.filter(111);

contributions.top(3).forEach(function(p, i) {
    console.log(p.pac_name + " (" + p.congress + ")" + ": $" + p.contribution_sum);
});
```

Complete JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eWr8Z/5/

Comment: Bastard!  You're dead right... filters apply to all dimensions globally and I failed to understand that concept.  You've broadened my understanding of Crossfilter and now I'm forever grateful.  You rock good sir!

Comment: Yup, to all dimensions and all groups. You form groups on dimensions (congress.group() to count records for each congress - use reduceSum to sum records, but see the API docs). But you don't need groups for top/bottom queries. Cheers :-)