# How to filter dimension by another variable in Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

My data has different columns, two of them are "date" and "node". I've created a date dimension called dateDim, simple enough. Now I'd like to filter that dimension based on the value of a certain node, this is, get all the values from dateDim whose node value equals a certain string. Is there any other way of doing so without adding the "node" variable as a key in the dimension definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crossfilter can't filter one dimension by another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837581/crossfilter-cant-filter-one-dimension-by-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but creating another dimension `nodeDim` and filtering on it will automagically impact `dateDime`.
This is the crux of what crossfilter does.

Comment: It sounds pretty close to what I wanted. I didn't think about how filtering a dimension affected the other ones. I'll try it. Thank you!